# Socket programming over internet

Tags: vb.net, sockets

I am making just a simple chat system using socket programming technique in vb.net .
It works fine on local network but how to use that over internet ..
I also try Port forwarding on my router ... May be my way is wrong . 
Please tell me the correct way for port forwarding .. and tell me how to connect client to the server ???
Am i have to use a public IP of server system ???

the server side code is this :

```
    Imports System.Net.Sockets
    Module Module1

        Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Dim clientListener As New TcpListener(12380)
    clientListener.Stop()
    clientListener.Start()
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Dim mySocket As Socket = clientListener.AcceptSocket()
    Console.WriteLine("")
    Dim recieveBuff(225) As Byte
    mySocket.Receive(recieveBuff, recieveBuff.Length, SocketFlags.None)
    Dim str As String = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieveBuff, 0, recieveBuff.Length).Trim(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(0))
    While Not str.StartsWith(".")
        Console.WriteLine(str)
        mySocket.Receive(recieveBuff, recieveBuff.Length, SocketFlags.None)
        str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recieveBuff, 0, recieveBuff.Length).Trim(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(0))
    End While
    Console.WriteLine("")
    clientListener.Stop()
    End Sub

    End Module
```

and the client side code is this : (those both are console applications)

```
    Imports System.Net.Sockets
    Imports System.IO

    Module Module1

    Sub Main()

    Try
        Console.WriteLine("Connecting to localhost ")
        Dim serverListener As New TcpClient("192.168.1.103", 12380)
        Dim readStream As Stream = serverListener.GetStream
        serverListener.SendBufferSize = 256
        Console.WriteLine("Input Lines:")
        Dim str As String = Console.ReadLine()
        While 370
            Dim sendBuff As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str)
            readStream.Write(sendBuff, 0, sendBuff.Length)
            If str.StartsWith(".") Then
                GoTo Done
            End If
            str = Console.ReadLine()

        End While
       Done:       Console.WriteLine("Done")
        Catch exp As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + exp.ToString())
       End Try
       End Sub
       End Module
```

Comment: Check that the firewall at both ends allows traffic through on that port. This is nothing to do with vb.net as such so might be a better fit on super user?

Comment: @CodeCaster It works fine on local network but i write the public IP of server then it does not works .... how to make it worl over internet ???

Comment: You need to explain what "does not work" means.

Comment: Dim serverListener As New TcpClient("110.36.2.78", 3009)
now i put the public Ip of server in tcpclient("here",3009)
on this line it gives error , his is the error :

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 110.36.2.78:3009

Comment: @codeCaster 
what about if i use TCP Hole Punching ?? i cannot get any example that how to do this in vb.net ??
can u have any idea about this ??

Comment: It looks like @MattWilko is right: allow port 3009 through the firewall, and perhaps you'll have to forward that port to the appropriate machine. No need for NAT punching, you're not writing a torrent client.

Comment: i did this but i want to do this with out doing the port forwarding in my router or any other router .. so thats why i want to do this with Hole Punching. because i hear that there is no need for port forwarding when we Hole Punching .....
any recommendation in thus regards ?????

Comment: The easiest way would be to set up a server somewhere and let all clients connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the public IP if the client is outside of your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to enable port forwarding in the router, port should be lie between 49152 and 65535 and Address would be the private address of the **server** ex:"192.168.1.x"
Make sure you start listening your server in the new port (the one between 49152 and 65535)
then go to [canyouseeme.org](http://canyouseeme.org/)

and type the new port that you used and press *check port*
if the result was **success** than your configuration was correct and your server now is accessible via internet ,if the result was a red **Error** then you might done something wrong,probably a firewall problem, or you need to change the router.
if you get **success** then you must change this line in every client instead of the old one:

```
      Dim serverListener As New TcpClient(YourPublicIpAdrees,NewPort)
```

To get your public ip address go here [myip](http://whatismyipaddress.com/).
This is how to send a socket over internet, try it and comment your result.