# Visual Basic Chat program via internet

Tags: vb.net, sockets, streaming

I would like to know what should I use to send a string (stream) to a client on a different computer via internet, through their internet IP.

I am completely successful with my LAN class I made that allows you to send and receive, but it only works via LAN and I got it to work once - Port Forward. I am even unable to achieve that again. I want the fastest way to get a string to a client, because I want to create a game in the future.

What I am using currently:

> System.Threading
>   System.Net
>   System.Net.Sockets
>   System.IO

What I have tried:

> Port forwarding
>   VPN (not successful, because I can't pay for something I don't know is going to work!)

What I have done:

> I have searched thousands of websites, but the only tutorials I got was for LAN.

Questions:

> I really would like to use Visual basic, but I also know C++, Python, Java. If this isn't possible with Visual Basic .Net, what should I use?
>   What is the best way to approach this?
>   Is Net sockets the right thing for this.
>   Is it possible to achieve this without downloading external programs and external paths. Meaning - Can I directly send someone a message without using something like VPN. I want the clients to ONLY install my program and not external programs as well. Port forward isn't an option of the client must do it as well, because not everyone has that knowledge.

Please, I am trying to achieve this for months! I would really like to achieve this, because I am over the basic structure and want to start making my products, but I can't afford to make it offline only. Especially after achieving to create updates for my program.

I would be so happy if someone can fully explain this to me. Don't stop sending information about this question please, I don't believe in information overflow!

I have learned myself all my programming knowledge through the internet - haven't done any courses, but I would do anything to be able to learn daily (24/7). Any Books that you can recommend or courses would be appreciated! Not basic tutorials please - Advance only!

Note:

> I can't pay something monthly for testing if I don't know it's going to work!
>   I am only 17 years old.
>   I don't have any source where I can get information from.
>   I don't mind using classes already created for this purpose, but I want to know how to create everything from scratch. I believe I have more control over things if I create it myself.

Please and thank you.
Rudi

Comment: I also learn visual basic. not vb.net but vb6. but whatever we try in related to your issue, I'm quite sure that there will be communication when there is a server and client, or, client-server-client. ...." Can I directly send someone a message without using something like VPN?". I think VPN here is like a server that we need to get in touch with others.

Comment: read here for necessary reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225890/socket-programming-over-internet

Comment: I have read that post before and it didn't work for me. I also want to achieve this by not Port forwarding on both sides - User friendliness is crucial!